# problem doing this trig integral $\int \frac{x^3dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{x^3dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$
$$x = 3\sin\theta$$
$$dx =3\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$\int \frac{(3\sin\theta)^33\cos\theta d\theta}{3\cos\theta }$$
$$\int 27\sin^3\theta d\theta$$
$$-27\cos\theta + 27\frac{9\cos^3}{3}$$

Replacing cosine by $\frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{3}$ does not give the correct answer what did I get wrong?

correct answer:
$$-\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}(x^2+18)}{3}$$

Comment: I don't know about whether there's any step that is wrong, but is there a reason you used a trig substitution rather than just $u = 9-x^2$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring because I am practicing trig subs

Comment: All right, well, your first error, then, is that $3^3 = 27 \neq 9$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring still does not reach the desired form

Comment: You may want to give the answer you reached then.  If you really replaced $\cos\theta$ with $\frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{3}$, then that's another error, but I can't tell if it affected your answer or whether it's a typo.

Comment: Also:  it may look different but still be correct.  If you got an answer of $(x+4)^2$ and I said the answer is $x^2+8x+16$, we're not wrong.

Comment: $9\sqrt{9-x^2}+9(9-x)^{3/2}$

Comment: $cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{3} $ seems to be ok

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960298/integrate-int-fracx3dx-sqrt1x2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148572/solving-an-indefinite-integral

Comment: Typesetting tip:  Typing `$\sin\theta$`, `$\cos\theta$`, `$\tan\theta$`, `$\csc\theta$`, `$\sec\theta$`, and `$\cot\theta$` produces $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\tan\theta$, $\csc\theta$, $\sec\theta$, and $\cot\theta$, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, this is not an integral for which trigonometric substitution is the best way to resolve it.  We could instead just use $u = 9 - x^2$ to instead find $x^2 = 9-u$ and $x\,dx = -\frac12\,du$.

This gives
$$\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,dx = \int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\cdot x\,dx = \int\frac{9-u}{\sqrt{u}}\left(-\frac12\right) \,du = -\frac12 \int\left(9u^{-1/2} - u^{1/2}\right)\,du$$

and you should be able to finish.

---

That said, we certainly *can* use a trig substitution as you have done.

It gives $$\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,dx = \int 27\sin^3\theta\,d\theta = 27\int(1-\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta\,d\theta$$

Here, we use the substitution $u = \cos\theta$ to write *(I know I've already harped on it, but the fact the standard method of evaluation uses substitution again to get rid of all the trig functions is a good indication we should've used a different substitution)*
$$-27\int (1-u^2)\,du = -27\cos\theta + 9\cos^3\theta$$

Substituting $\cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$:
$$-27\left(\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}\right) + 9\left(\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}\right)^3 = -\frac13\sqrt{9-x^2}\cdot \left(27 - (9-x^2)\right) = -\frac13\sqrt{9-x^2}(18+x^2)$$

---

Which errors does this show in your attempt?

- Note that when integrating $27\sin^3\theta$ the coefficient of $\cos^3\theta$ is $9$.
- You have at times used $\cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{3}$ (the wrong one) and at times $\cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$ (the correct one).  It's not clear why you have this inconsistency.
- You still seem to have a point you've written $3^3 = 9$.

Answer (score 2):

**Correction of OP:**
$$\cos \theta =\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 \theta} =\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{9}} =\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{9-x^2}$$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =27 \int \sin ^3 \theta d \theta \\
& =-27 \int\left(1-\cos ^2 \theta\right) d(\cos \theta) \\
& =-27\left(\cos \theta-\frac{\cos ^3 \theta}{3}\right) \\
& =-9 \cos \theta\left(3-\cos ^2 \theta\right)\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}\left(x^2+18\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**Suggested solution**
$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}} d x 
= & -\int x^2 d \sqrt{9-x^2} \\
= & -x^2 \sqrt{9-x^2}-\int \sqrt{9-x^2} d\left(9-x^2\right) \\
= & -x^2 \sqrt{9-x^2}-\frac{2\left(9-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+C \\
= & -\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}\left[3 x^2+2\left(9-x^2\right)\right]+C \\
= & -\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}\left(x^2+18\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$